# What is the proper way to say "14 Registered Students"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, subjects

Which should it be?

"14 Registered Students"

or

"14 Students Registered"

Comment: I apologize for my errors. This is for a website where I will only say one of the two lines from my post. It won't be in any essay or paper or something to that nature. It will be on a website, where I need to abbreviate.

Comment: So I guess either will work?

Comment: You don't need to apologise for your spelling misteaks, we all make them, and you've fixed it now.  Yes, either phrase is OK and any choice between them depends on the context in which they are to be used.  But don't put explanatory information into comments, edit it into your question.  Right now it is entirely closeworthy precisely because it is unanswerable without explanation of the context in which the words are to be used.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark --"spelling misteaks"... classic...

Answer (score 1):

"14 Registered Students" indicates that there are 14 registered students. This would be the subject of a sentence, for example, "There are 14 registered students in the class." This usage is more static and does not show action.

"14 Students Registered" gives a slightly different meaning: In this case you are using *registered* as a verb, meaning that 14 students did the action of registering. This is a more active use, for example, "14 students registered for the course" (shows the action of this happening).

Comment: We are given no context. "14 Students Registered" may be a deletion from "14 Students have Registered" or "14 Students are Registered". With deletion, ambiguity often arises.